# How can I remove a crowd of people from a scene while keeping one person in the shot

Tags: premiere, after-effects, editing, adobe, compositing

I'm trying to film in a city with one person being the focus point, and the goal is to make the city look deserted.  If the city is always busy and full of people, is there a way for me to remove the people in After Effects or Premiere Pro?  I would think that one could just make a composite shot of only the parts of the image that stay constant, but I have no idea how to even approach that.  How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into the new Content-aware fill feature? It might be what you're looking for. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/content-aware-fill.html

Comment: @Joshjurg I've definitely used that a lot in photoshop, didn't know it was in ae.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it was a new feature added this past spring. On the rare occasion I used it, it rocked for what I needed.

For this need though, the scene may be too busy for this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the camera moving? If it's a still shot you could make a clean plate of the empty city in Photoshop and use a green screen for the actor. If you don't want the shot locked-off you can cheat add some movement to the frame in post, but big changes in perspective would require recreating the city in 3D.

[image]

Interestingly one of the earliest photographs of a human being was by accident — owing to the extremely long exposures required by the early emulsions, anything moving would blur out. In a photo by Louis Daguerre there was a guy standing having his shoes shined and he appears to be the only person in Paris. You could use the long exposure technique to get your background.

Comment: The frames are most likely going to be still, as I don't have a steadicam and would prefer the frame to not be shakey